# ConcurrentModificationException when trying to sum numbers of an Arraylist using multiple threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm new to multithreading in general, so I still don't fully understand it. I don't get why my code is having issues. I'm trying to populate an ArrayList with the first 1000 numbers, and then sum all of them using three threads.

```
public class Tst extends Thread {
    private static int sum = 0;
    private final int MOD = 3;
    private final int compare;
    private static final int LIMIT = 1000;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Tst(int compare){
        this.compare=compare;
    }

    public synchronized void populate() throws InterruptedException{
        for(int i=0; i<=Tst.LIMIT; i++){
            if (i%this.MOD == this.compare){
            list.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void sum() throws InterruptedException{
        for (Integer ger : list){
            if (ger%MOD == this.compare){
                sum+=ger;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            populate();
            sum();
            System.out.println(sum);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tst.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tst tst1 = new Tst(0);
        tst1.start();
        Tst tst2 = new Tst(1);
        tst2.start();
        Tst tst3 = new Tst(2);
        tst3.start();
    }
}
```

I expected it to print "500.500‬", but instead it prints this:

```
162241
328741
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1042)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:996)
    at tst.Tst.sum(Tst.java:38)
    at tst.Tst.run(Tst.java:50)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Unrelated: please use meaningful (and pronouncable) names in your code. Tst ... means nothing. Why not call it ListAccessThreadTester ... or something like.

Comment: You have done nothing to prevent one thread from getting into the `sum()` function while other threads might still be in the `populate()` call. The exception will be thrown if _any_ change is made to the list while a `for(Integer ger : list)` loop is running. It doesn't matter that the different threads are operating on different members of the list.

Comment: Your synchronization is useless because each thread is synchronizing on itself. Try making your methods static and you'll see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is happening because your methods are synchronized in "object level", I mean, the monitor lock it uses is of a particular object (tst1,tst2,tst3). In other words, each synchronized method is using a different lock.
Change your synchronized methods to static as a first step to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, it solved them problem. However if i do that i won't be able to use the "compare" variable (I need each thread to have a different value so no number being added to the list or being summed is repeated).

Comment: There are multiple ways of solving this last issue with 'compare' variable. The easiest would be passing the instance variables as parameters to your new static methods (sum and populate)

Answer (score 0):

while run of tst1 is counting the sum in for-each then run of tst2 might increasing the size of list. So its throwing concurrent modification exception. Using a join can help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tst tst1 = new Tst(0);
    tst1.start();
    tst1.join()
    Tst tst2 = new Tst(1);
    tst2.start();
    tst1.join()
    Tst tst3 = new Tst(2);
    tst3.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the semantic of `synchronized` method, each one uses different lock object in your case, do it this way:

```
 class SynchList {
   private int sum = 0;
   private final int MOD = 3;
   private int compare;
   private final int LIMIT = 1000;
   private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   public synchronized void populate( int compare) throws InterruptedException{
       for(int i=0; i<=LIMIT; i++){
           if (i%this.MOD == compare){
           list.add(i);
           }
       }
   }

   public synchronized void sum( int compare ) throws InterruptedException{
       for (Integer ger : list){
           if (ger%MOD == compare){
               sum+=ger;
           }
           System.out.println( sum );
       }
   }
}

class Tst extends Thread {
    int compare;
    SynchList synchList;
    public Tst(int compare, SynchList synchList)
    {
        this.compare= compare;
        this.synchList = synchList;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            synchList.populate( compare );
            synchList.sum( compare );

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tst.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchList synchList = new SynchList();

        Tst tst1 = new Tst( 0 , synchList );
        tst1.start();
        Tst tst2 = new Tst( 1, synchList );
        tst2.start();
        Tst tst3 = new Tst( 2, synchList );
        tst3.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of synchronized methods isn't doing what you think it's doing. The way your code is written, the methods "sum" and "populate" are protected
from running at the same time, but *only on the same thread instance*. That means calls to "sum" and "populate" for a single `Tst` object will happen one at a time,
but simultaneous calls to "sum" on different object instances will be allowed to happen concurrently.

Using `synchronized` on a method is equivalent to writing a method that is wrapped
with `synchronized(this) { ... }` around the entire method body. With three different instances created – `tst1`, `tst2`, and `tst3` – this form of synchronization
doesn't guard *across object instances*. Instead, it guarantees that only one of `populate` or `sum` will be running at a time on a single object; any other calls to one of
those methods (on the same object instance) will wait until the prior one finishes.
Take a look at [8.4.3.6. synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) in the Java Language Specification
for more detail.

Your use of `static` might also not be doing what you think it's doing. Your code also shares things across all instances of the `Tst` thread class – namely, `sum` and `list`. Because these are defined as `static`,
there will be a one `sum` and one `list`. There is no thread safety in your code to guard against concurrent changes to either of those.
For example, as threads are updating
"sum" (with the line: `sum+=ger`), the results will be non-deterministic. That is, you will likely see different results every time you run it.

Another example of unexpected behavior with multiple threads and a single static variable is `list` – that will grow over time which can result in concurrency issues. [The Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) says:

> *Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.*

Modifications include adding values as well as growing the backing array store. Without specifying a starting size – `new ArrayList()` – it will default to 10 or possibly some other relatively small number depending on which JVM version you're using. Once one thread tries to add an item that exceeds the ArrayList's capacity, it will trigger an automatic resize.

> *Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.*